# Is there a way to make the CSS property mask-image responsive?

Tags: css, sass

I want this image to expand the width of the page. How can I get the mask to expand too? If I set the width/height properties to 100% the mask does not scale, It just repeats.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do.
http://cdpn.io/tHimv

Comment: Please provide a JSfiddle version we can access

Comment: Also a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HpCXX/

Comment: @Timidfriendly Codepen is an editor like Jsfiddle. Click "Edit this Pen" in the footer, or go here: http://codepen.io/zerostyle/pen/tHimv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  -webkit-mask: url('http://test.com/mask.svg') center center / cover;
  -webkit-mask-size: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was using Firefox where the -webit- code won't work of course.

This scales `-webkit-mask-size: 100% 100%`

If you want a more crossbrowser solution you can check this link out http://thenittygritty.co/css-masking

Answer (score 0):

```
.mask1 {
            -webkit-mask-image: url(./slider/003.png);
            mask-image: url(./slider/003.png);
            -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
            mask-repeat: no-repeat;
            -webkit-mask-size: 100% 100%;
        }
```

Dont use **width: 100%;height: 100%;**

Just use **-webkit-mask-size: 100% 100%;**